# Python, как распарсить namedtuple, превращенный в строку

Tags: python, парсер

Допустим, у нас есть строка: "Pair(x1=1, x2=2)", полученная таким способом:

```
Pair = namedtuple('Pair', 'x1 x2')
pair = Pair(1, 2)
pair = str(pair)
```

Существует ли простой способ распарсить подобные строки? Иными словами, преобразовать ее, скажем, в словарь {'x1': 1, 'x2': 2}

Comment: Если забить на безопасность: `eval('Pair(x1=1, x2=2)')._asdict()`

Comment: Вам точно хочется парсить строковое представление? :) Мб просто у `pair` возьмете словарь: `pair = Pair(1, 2)` + `print(pair._asdict())`. Этот же словарь можно в json превратить. Если `pair._asdict()` не нравится,  можно сохранять/загружать объект через pickle

Comment: так не проще ли namedtuple сразу _asdict?